# Finds links in text input and turns them into html links in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to find the links in text input and turns them into html links in angularjs.Here is my code but its not working.
Html

```
<div class="item item-body" ng-bind-html="{{deal.notification_details}} | linky" >
</div>
```

controller.js

```
 $scope.deal=[{id:'0',notification_details:'sample description http://www/example.com'}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
<div class="item item-body" ng-bind-html="deal.notification_details | linky"></div>
```

`ngBindHtml` expects an expression, hence you don't have to use interpolation markers `{{ ... }}`.

To open a link in new tab you would use target setting of the linky filter:

```
ng-bind-html="deal.notification_details | linky:'_blank'"
```

Comment: Its worked.But its opened in app itself.How can i open the in external browser??

Comment: Add `target="_blank"` attribute to the link: `ng-bind-html="deal.notification_details | linky:'_blank'"`

Comment: Where i will give `target="_blank"`

Comment: See updated answer for how you can add target attribute.

Comment: It should work, here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/heI7ytOS7xWa1ZZiZrWj?p=preview.

Comment: Works fine in browser,but not in android phone

Comment: You will have to manually open a window then as far as I know, with `window.open`.

Answer (score 1):

**$scope.deal** it is **json objec**t so get first array item is start from 0

```
<div class="item item-body" ng-bind-html="deal[0].notification_details | linky"></div>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jjLtLwhv/1/)

Comment: Based on `$scope.deal` structure, looks like OP uses `ngRepeat` like this `ng-repeat="deal in deals"`.

Comment: @dfsq where didn't the op uses ng-repeat in the question??

Comment: How can i open link in browser ,i tried `_blank` but its not worked.